# Go passing parameters of pointers or copies to functions

Tags: go

I am contemplating on the Go pointers, passing variables as parameters to functions by value or by reference. In a book I have encountered a good example, which is the first code snippet below, on passing a pointer.

The first version is working as expected, in function that takes parameter of a pointer makes changes to the variable itself, not on a copy of it. But the second example below I am tinkering with works on a copy of it. I have thought they should behave equivalently, and second one to work on the variable passed as parameter, not on copy of it.

Essentially, what these two versions of the function is behaving different?

[version in the book](https://play.golang.org/p/vsfiLd5a4U), passing parameters by reference:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
// simple function to add 1 to a
func add1(a *int) int {
    *a = *a+1 // we changed value of a
    return *a // return new value of a
}

func main() {
    x := 3

    fmt.Println("x = ", x)  // should print "x = 3"

    x1 := add1(&x)  // call add1(&x) pass memory address of x

    fmt.Println("x+1 = ", x1) // should print "x+1 = 4"
    fmt.Println("x = ", x)    // should print "x = 4"
}
```

[my alternative tinkering version](https://play.golang.org/p/VX7pt6XmQP), passing pointer parameter:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
// simple function to add 1 to a
func add1(a int) int {
    p := &a
    *p = *p+1 // we changed value of a
    return *p // return new value of a
}
func main(){
    fmt.Println("this is my go playground.")

        x := 3

        fmt.Println("x = ", x)  // should print "x = 3"

        x1 := add1(x)  // call add1(&x) pass memory address of x

        fmt.Println("x+1 = ", x1) // should print "x+1 = 4"
        fmt.Println("x = ", x)    // should print "x = 4"   
}
```

Comment: Note that in your version when you do `p := &a` your're getting a reference of `a` which is a copy of `x`, not a reference of `x`. Imagine it like this. You have a drawing. Taking a reference of the drawing you get the paper. Performing operations on this paper (erase, draw etc) alters the drawing. Now, xerox (photocopy) that drawing. Take a reference of the copy you get a paper but performing operations on *this* paper will only alter the copy, not the original drawing. That's what passing by value is.

Comment: Go has **absolutely** **no** notion of "pass by reference". Stop using this term, stop thinking along such (broken) concepts and talk/think/use pointers and all is fine. Never think of a pointer argument as "pass by reference". It is not.

Comment: @slebetman `p := &a` is assigning `p` the address of `a`, creating a pointer. It is in no way, shape, or form a reference. `a` is a copy of `x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why should they behave equivalently? In the first example you pass a pointer (to `int`), in the second example you pass an `int` value.

What happens in the 2nd example is that you pass an `int` value. Parameters in functions work like local variables. A local variable called `a` of type `int` will be created, and will be initialized with the value you passed (`3` which is the value of `x`). This local variable is addressable like any other variables.

You take its address (`p := &a`) and you increment the value pointed by this pointer (which is variable `a` itself). And you return the value pointed by it which is the incremented value of `a`.

Outside from where you called this `add1()` function, the value of `x` is not modified because only the local copy `a` was modified.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in `golang` is `pass by value`, which means the function always gets a copy of the thing being passed.
In your second example, the value of `x` is actually sent to the function `add`, so any modification you made to the copy wont affect the original `x`.

See [pass by value](https://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value)